# Which of the following relations on Z are order relations?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Which of the following relations on Z are order relations?

- R1:xR1y $\leftarrow \rightarrow$ x$\le$y;
- R2:xR2y $\leftarrow \rightarrow$ x$\ge$y;
- R3:xR3y $\leftarrow \rightarrow$ x$\lt$y;
- R4:xR4y $\leftarrow \rightarrow$ x$^2$ $\le$ y$^2$;
- R5:xR5y $\leftarrow \rightarrow$ x=y;
- R6:xR6y $\leftarrow \rightarrow$ $\frac{x}{y}$
- R7:xR7y $\leftarrow \rightarrow$ GCD(x,y)=1

reflective if for any x belonging to A xRx

symmetric if xRy yRx follows

antisymmetric if xRy and yRx imply x = y

transitive if xRy and yRz implies xRz

Comment: This is not a site for homework service. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: Proof read before you post!  R6 is not  stated correctly.

Comment: I do not understand